# Create generate random number function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create the function in SQL Server. In this function I have generated the random number, but function not generated.

```
Create function [GetRandomNumber]
(
)
RETURNS bigint
as 
Begin
Declare @randomNo int
 set  @randomNo = (select round(rand(checksum(newid()))*(10001)+50000,0) as [GetRandomNumber])
 return @randomNo
End
```

this is generated in following error:

> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'newid' within a function.
>   Msg 443, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetRandomNumber, Line 8
>   Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'rand' within a function.

Comment: As the message said, you can't do that. pass in the newid() as a parameter

Comment: Except for CLR functions, user-defined functions must be deterministic. For that reason, you can't write a function to produce a random number. You could write a stored procedure to do so -- or you could just use `CONVERT(INT, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4))` (or `BIGINT` and `8`, your return type and expression contradict each other).

Comment: @JeroenMostert no any way to i have to create the generate the random number in function.

Comment: Then your only recourse (if you don't want hacky half-solutions like passing in the non-deterministic part, which is easy to get wrong) is a non-deterministic [CLR function](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-scalar-valued-functions), as stated before. Building and installing these is not entirely trivial, though (but as a bonus, generating a good random number in a range is far easier in C#).

Comment: yes i write a store procedure to do but i am just try to it

Comment: A stored procedure with a single-value result set or an output variable would do. Unlike a function, though, you can't call these per row.

Comment: Well, there's one work-around I can think off.  But it's slightly ugly.  Pass a random float as a variable to the function via f.e. [RAND()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql). Then use that variable in the function.

Comment: NEWID() is a guid/Uniqueidentifier. Not a random number

Comment: @WesleyNightingale: SQL Server (or rather Windows, and the sqlos wrapper on Linux) generates v4 GUIDs, which are made up of 122 random bits plus 4 identifying them as a v4 GUID. `RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))` is "random enough" for most purposes. `RAND(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4))` is a (slower) alternative if you don't trust `NEWID()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. However, it will require a little bit of extra legwork.

First, you need to create a view, like the one below:

```
create view dbo.sys_NDF
as
select rand() as [ValueRand], newid() as [ValueGUID],
  rand(checksum(newid())) as [SeededRand];
go
```

The trick is that you cannot call these system functions directly from your UDF, however you can query a view that returns their values. You can later expand it with other functions / columns if need be.

As such, your function starts to look like the following:

```
Create function [GetRandomNumber]()
RETURNS bigint as begin
return (select round(v.SeededRand * 10001 + 50000, 0) from dbo.sys_NDF v);
end;
go
```

Comment: i am just check in function in possible or not to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Create SP instead of function. Because some system function are not allowed in user defined function.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  [GetRandomNumber]
as 
Begin
Declare @randomNo int
 set  @randomNo = (select round(rand(checksum(newid()))*(10001)+50000,0) as [GetRandomNumber])
 return @randomNo
End

GO
 DECLARE @returnvalue INT
 EXEC @returnvalue = GetRandomNumber
 SELECT @returnvalue
```

Comment: The problem there is that you cannot `OUTER APPLY` to a stored procedure.